# Foursquare & Heroku: certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, heroku, foursquare

I obtained a key/secret for userless access at the foursquare developer site and now I want to fetch data with the use of the `foursquare2` gem:

```
    @foursquare = Foursquare2::Client.new(:client_id => 'xxx', :client_secret => 'yyy')
```

This works fine on localhost but on Heroku I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed)
```

I didn't set up any SSL or Omniauth within the app.

**Update:** Found the solution! You have to pass in a ssl hash with the path to heroku's certificates path.

```
@foursquare = Foursquare2::Client.new(:client_id => 'xxx',
                                      :client_secret => 'yyy',
                                      :ssl => { :verify => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER, :ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt' })
```

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978184/omniauth-with-facebook-not-working-on-production

Answer (score 0):

I also mentioned that problem under ruby 1.9.3. After downgrading to ruby 1.9.2 I didn't get that error anymore...