# ominauth with facebook not working with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, heroku, omniauth

Login with Fb worked fine when I was hosting locally but I'm having issues now that it's on heroku. I already updated the domain on FB associated with my app from localhost:3000 to myapp.herokuapp.com

I've also checked out this thread [omniauth with facebook not working on production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978184/omniauth-with-facebook-not-working-on-production) and tried adding the 'client_options' hash to my initializer file and am still having trouble. I don't know if this is relevant, but when I try and navigate to /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt I get a "No such file or directory" error.

When I click login to FB on my app (http://playedbyme.herokuapp.com/) I get a callback error.

Here is what my OmniAuth initializer file looks like:

```
  Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, 'MY_APP_ID', 'MY_SECRET_KEY',
      {:client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}}}
  end
```

UPDATE: I think that it's some sort of issue with my database. When I run "heroku run rake db:migrate" I get an error

```
   rake aborted!
   An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
   PG::Error: ERROR:  column "id" of relation "parties" already exists
   : ALTER TABLE "parties" RENAME COLUMN "party_id" TO "id"
```

But, I don't have a column named party_id in my Parties table

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your CA certs path is correct. You can check that on your heroku servers by running:

```
heroku run bash
```

and then running openssl to display the proper path:

```
$ openssl version -a
 OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011 
 OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

You should find the ca_certificates.crt file at $OPENSSLDIR/certs/ca-certificates.crt

Make sure you are also specifying your Facebook permissions in `scope` as per [omniauth setup](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Setting-up-SSL-certificate-locations-in-Linux) in `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'YOUR_APP_ID', 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY',
           {:scope => 'PERMISSION_1, PERMISSION_2, ETC', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}}}
end
```

Also ensure you restart rails after making changes to this file.

**Edit**

To fix your DB problem, you may want to look at resetting your DB and recreating it:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE --confirm YOUR_APP_NAME
heroku run rake db:setup
heroku restart
heroku open
```

Comment: I did that and got this:


OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
built on: Thu Feb 10 01:45:33 UTC 2011
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(ptr,char) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(ptr2) 
compiler: cc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -O3 -Wa,--noexecstack -g -Wall -DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
~ $

Doesn't that mean I have the correct path?

Comment: Hmm - can you also try the path `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`? This is another possible location for the file.

Comment: Edited for some other things to try - I believe `/usr/lib/ssl/certs` is the right location :(

Comment: Checked out /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt - no file or directory. Should I be able to open /usr/lib/ssl/certs in terminal?

Comment: I think I'm having some sort of problem with my database